# MongoDb nested remove query

Tags: c#, mongodb, subquery

I have a collection with a scheme like this:

```
[
    Folder: {
        _id: ObjectId(...),
        Item: [{
            _id: ObjectId(...),
            Version: [{
                _id: ObjectId(...),
                ConfirmedDevices: [ObjectId(...), ...]
            }, ...]
        }, ...]
    }
]
```

I need to remove some certain id's from `ConfirmedDevices` array of every version of every item in a certain `Folder`. In other words, I have a folderId which I need to select the folder by. Then I have a list of id's, which need to be **removed** from all confirmed devices existing in that folder.

I need to do this over C# driver. Actually I already wrote the code which does this, but that requires to make a query to db for each version of every item in the folder. And this causes performance problems in case of many items on the folder.

The logic of what I'm saying is this, take it as a pseudo code.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < folder.items.Count; i++)
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < item.versions.Count; j++)
    {
        db.folders.update(
            {"_id": ObjectId("...") }, 
            { $pull: { "Items." + i + ".Versions." + j + ".ConfirmedDevices": { $in: [ ObjectId("...") ] } } },
            { multi: true }
        );
    }
}
```

I know mongodb's nested queries are on the dark and poor side of the concept. But I can't confirm that this is impossible.

Is there anyway that I can achive this on one go?
(regular mongodb query will be enough, I can convert it to C# version)

Answer (score 0):

I think $elemMatch is what you are missing. This will allow you to identify items using fields in embedded documents. This in combination with $in and $pull you will be able to achieve what you want

[MongoDB Documentation - ElemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Comment: Is there any way you can elaborate? Maybe fire up an example?